# remove line between tabWidget and frameLayout

Tags: android, line, pixel, android-tabhost, android-framelayout

I tried everything, but i can't remove the line between tabWidget and frameLayout of my tabhost. I tried fadingEdge=none, margin=0 but nothing to do.

I'm refering to the **black line**; **the white line is a simple view** (1) between tabWidget and frameLayout to "*understand*" where the problem is...and it seems to be of frameLayout not of tabWidget
Here my image:
http://imageshack.us/f/641/screenlme.jpg/

(1)

```
<View
ndroid:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="4dip"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
</View>
```

Have you got some advise for me??

EDIT 1: I added fo frameLayout

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_tab_body_patched"
```

and now the black line moved a bit down; so it's a problem of linearlayout:
http://imageshack.us/f/233/screenav.jpg/

Comment: Check this post, seems to hold an answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221959/tabhost-bottom-border-line-android

Answer (score 2):

in your xml file use the following line.

```
android:tabStripEnabled="false"
```

you have to put this attribute for the TabWidget of tabs in xml.

Comment: it tried that but it isn't a problem of tabwidget. the fade edge effect (it seems a fadeedge effect...) is in the framelayout on in its content even with fadingEdge=none still there's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Its Work for Me Very Nicely:

Apply a custom theme to your activity, and null out the **android:windowContentOverlay** attribute.

Define a theme in **themes.xml**:

`<style name="YourTheme" parent="if you want"> ...

<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>`

Apply the theme on your application or the activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<application android:theme="@style/YourTheme" ... >`